# Rich text box using inkedit control in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a vba user form with an inkedit control, which will allow the user to enter rich text data. I have been searching all over Google but not able to find any proper vba code. Is there any site or documentation I can refer to to do

- bullets
- Increase/ decrease indent

Any help is highly appreciated

**I have managed to create the rich text box using the inkedit control up to some extent. Posting it below for reference**

But any further help is greatly appreciated

First set the InkInsertMode and InkMode to 0, so it will behave as a normal text box. 
I added few cmd buttons for **bold, italics, underline, color, bullet and indent**.

Setting the font to bold, underline or italics is easy, can be done by using the **.SelBold, .SelItalics or SelUnderline** to true or false by code.

Also for color we can use the SelColor property.

Tricky part is the bullet and indent, indent I have done by editing the rtf output of the selected text.

Inkedit has 2 outputs, .Text and TextRtf which returns the text with the rtf tags.

And we have to edit the rtf code to achieve bullet and indent.

Store the .SelRTF in a variable. This will give the rtf code if the selected text. Any line having an indent will have the string **\li360\sl240\slmult1**, li360 is the indent part, to increase keep adding 360 to it, and subtract to decrease. Replace li360 and post it back to inkedit.

Inkedit.SelRTF= NewTxt

I am working on the rest.

Now how to show this in Excel sheet?

Trick is we have to pass the rtf output.

I have placed a text box on a sheet.
Open clipboard as rtf format. Copy .TextRTF and paste it back in the shape.

I am working on the rest if I can make them work.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please detail what you're trying to do? Do you need the text recognition feature or just use inkEdit because you want to enable Rich text?

Comment: Hi, I just want to enable rich text box, where user can format the text, like wordpad

Comment: http://imgur.com/THCqe2W Do you need anything more than this? Because this is a normal Excel 2010 textbox.

Comment: I would want the text box in a user form, not on the excel sheet.

Comment: I don't think it can be done (maybe by inkedit, but I am very unfamiliar with that). Others have had this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525862/rich-text-input-using-microsoft-inkedit?rq=1 but no answer. MSDN does not give any usable examples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698514(v=vs.85).aspx I upvoted so others can see it and help but if I were you I would start looking into other solutions.

Comment: Thank you Devid. Yes it's doable using inkedit, I have cracked some part of it. But it's good to have some reference.

Comment: Please edit your question if you find out how to do it, I would be very interested to know and this is an unresolved matter. It would be good to have in Stack overflow!

Comment: Sure, I have posted my progress above